# Why does the getArea((l / 3), (n - 1) return only null value?

Tags: vb.net

Why does the function getArea return NULL/Nothing

```
  Module Module3
  Dim noOfTriangles As Integer = (3 / 2)
  Sub main()
    Dim l As Single
    Dim n As Integer
    l = Console.ReadLine()
    n = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(getArea(l, n))
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Function getArea(ByVal l As Single, ByVal n As Integer)
    Dim area As Single = 1
    If n = 0 Then
      Return Nothing
    Else
      noOfTriangles = noOfTriangles * 2
      Return (((3 ^ (1 / 2)) / 4) * (l ^ 2) + (noOfTriangles * getArea((l / 3), (n - 1))))
    End If
  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Don't just post your code and ask, why it does not work. Tell us, what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried to solve the problem. Your problem could be related to the first line. (3 / 2) As Integer is not 1.5.

Comment: how would this ever return anything BUT null?  getArea is recursive and the end condition (n = 0) returns Nothing, so as the stack is unwound that "nothing" just propagates.  Perhaps the n=0 case should return some type of identity value, like 1 or 0?

Comment: every time you run the code with any parameters,  getArea((l / 3), (n - 1) has the value nothing!

Comment: right that's what you told it to do :)  What should the value of getArea(l/3, 0) be for your algorithm?

Comment: Go into your project properties and turn on Option Strict.  Your Function declaration does not specify a return type.  Also, what are you typing for the values of l and n when the program asks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it gets you any closer to what you're looking for:

```
    Module Module3
  Dim noOfTriangles As double = (3 / 2)
  Sub main()
    Dim l As Single
    Dim n As Integer
    l = Single.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    n = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine(getArea(l, n))
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Function getArea(ByVal l As Single, ByVal n As Integer) as Double
    Dim area As Single = 1
    If n = 0 Then
      Return Nothing
    Else
      noOfTriangles = noOfTriangles * 2
      Return (((3 ^ (1 / 2)) / 4) * (l ^ 2) + (noOfTriangles * getArea((l / 3), (n - 1))))
    End If
  End Function
End Module
```